# Can the adjective "squalid" be used to describe a person?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

As the title states: Can **squalid** be used to describe a person that has really fallen on hard times (ragged clothing, worn-out, haggard etc.)?

And if it can be used as such, how does it compare to **shabby**, i.e. which has a stronger connotation of *run-down-ness*?

All descriptions of **squalid** in dictionaries or example texts I found always use the word for buildings, areas, streets, but none I found uses it to describe a human directly.

Comment: I've never encountered "squalid" applied to a human being, in conversation or literature. If I did, I'd expect it to be used metaphorically (drawing parallels between the person and a dilapidated building), or jocularly (relishing an unusual turn of phrase, or an unusually cruel description). Note, to my ear, *squalid* has a *much stronger* sense of filth and disrepair than *shabby* (which, at its gentlest, can be applied to a schoolchild who hasn't learned to dress himself properly yet).

Comment: @DanBron thanks, that's all I wanted to know. If you write your comment up as an answer I'd gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: @DanBron 'Squalid' is also much used in relation to schemes that border on criminality. One sometimes speaks of a 'squalid idea'. That is about as close as it gets to human beings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never encountered "*squalid*" applied to a human being, in conversation or literature. If I did, I'd expect it to be used metaphorically (drawing parallels between the person and a dilapidated building), or jocularly (relishing an unusual turn of phrase, or an unusually cruel description).

Note, to my ear, *squalid* has a **much stronger** sense of filth and disrepair than *shabby* (which, at its gentlest, can be applied to a schoolchild who hasn't learned to dress himself properly yet).

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

OED s.v., sense 1c: "Of persons, their appearance, etc."

R.W. Emerson, *Poems* 76 (1847): "Is yon squalid peasant all / That this proud nursery could breed?"

Answer (score 0):

I think that "squalid" can be used of a human being, but it doesn't have *any* connotation of having fallen on hard times, or being worn-out, haggard or merely shabby. Instead, what it means is that the person is being represented as having bad morals or attitudes - one might call "squalid" someone who is, say, a gay prostitute who has no hesitation being a police spy within the gay community, or who is a pusher of hard drugs. The malodorous run-downness of an urban district, building or living space translates to the metaphorical bad odour and sense of collapse that a person gives off who isn't in good order morally.